# Link rendering on PDF export of careers should be better

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Currently the link rendering of a link in a text area of careers renders as all black without an underline.  At the very minimum this sucks for computer users and is completely worthless for people who print out the pdf.  I propose two features:

1. Links should be rendered as blue with an underline (or at least blue!)
2. Links should (maybe optionally?) be rendered back to markdown when printed, and (again maybe optionally?) shortened, for the print version.