# Careers PDF, expand links to show url in copy areas

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, design, markdown

When you export a PDF of your careers profile, if you have links to other sites in a copy area like "Background" those links aren't shown.

It would be nice if the link in the markdown was rendered out as well

I.E.

Original markdown

```
I like to go for a [jog every now and then](https://www.strava.com/athletes/6698304).
```

And in the PDF if it rendered like this:

I like to go for a jog every now and then (https://www.strava.com/athletes/6698304).

---

I think that would make using links in the copy areas more practical across the different mediums or web and print.

I realise this request is similar to [Link rendering on PDF export of careers should be better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250912) but there are couple of thoughts around the accepted answer.

- It assumes that the profile owner will always be making the PDF which would not be true if the public profile is shared with an HR department that may decide to get a PDF version of the CV.
- If you write the content assuming that people understand there is a link there, when reading without that context in the PDF version your content can come across as slightly odd.
- There is already something similar for when you link to open source projects or articles so the idea of having the link accessible in print is already there.

Answer (score 2):

This would certainly be a useful feature. Most of the heavy lifting here is done by our markdown processor, which is battle-tested and has benefited from many years of use and hardening. We have to be careful making changes to the way this works so as not to introduce any vulnerabilities or regressions.

That said, never say never! We'll definitely see if we can find a low-risk, low-cost solution.

Thanks for the suggestion.

**Update**

We've implemented a rudimentary function that toggles the display of link URLs when exporting a PDF. The toggle control is located at the bottom of the dropdown menu at the top of the PDF preview page.